# Flipping the UILabel

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-animation

I want to use the CABasicAnimation to flip the UILabel. Animation will repeat forever and will change the text of UILabel between two different values.

```
- (void)animateLabel
{
     [self.myLabel.layer addAdnimation:[self labelAnimation]  forKey:@"flip"];
}

- (CAAnimation*)labelAnimation
{
     CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
     [animation setRepeatCount:NSIntegerMax];
     [animation setAutoreverses:YES];
     [animation setDuration:2.0];
     [animation setDelegate:self];
     CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 1, 0, 0);
     [animation  setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
     return animation;
}
```

Now, I tried using the delegate but the delegate method is only when the animation first begins. Rather I need to be able to know the the label completes one cycle. Is there some convenience method or way to do it with CALayer or do I have to use CADisplay link or timer ? I would like to thank you before hand for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is the way you're supposed to do it according to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAMediaTiming_protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CAMediaTiming).

> Setting this property to `HUGE_VALF` will cause the animation to repeat forever.

Comment: Well this already repeats forever. Do you see me using NSIntegerMax. So, what is wrong with the code above then ?

Answer (score 2):

To get notified on each cycle, setRepeatsCount to 1. You'll then get notified in the delegate animationDidStop:finished. You would then simply add the same animation again.

```
 - (void)animateLabel
 {
     [self.myLabel.layer addAdnimation:[self labelAnimation]  forKey:@"flip"];
 }

 - (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    [self animateLabel];
    // do other stuff
}

 - (CAAnimation*)labelAnimation
 {
     CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
     [animation setRepeatCount:1];
     [animation setAutoreverses:YES];
     [animation setDuration:2.0];
     [animation setDelegate:self];
      CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 1, 0, 0);
     [animation  setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
      return animation;
  }
```

Comment: @insane-36 did this answer help you solve the issue? if yes, would you be so kind to accept it?